# How to add a string subscript to a column name of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I want to add a string subscript M to string SE like: **SE<sub>M</sub>** to columnnames of my dataframe but when I use this code, I get NA instead of SE<sub>M</sub>

Code:

```
colnames(df) <- c("Mean", expression = ('SE'['M']), "Min", "Max")
```

Output

```
Mean     NA    Min    Max
```

Later I have to add this dataframe to a word document using library(officer), so I call this in the next step:

```
body_add_table(doc, df, style = "Table Professional)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What are you trying to use this for? If it is to display text wit subscript as a column header there are a few different ways of doing that.

Comment: @qdread yes it is to display the column header.

Comment: Is this for a Rmarkdown document?

Comment: @qdread No I have to add this dataframe to a word document using library(officer), so i call this in the next step: body_add_table(doc, df, style = "Table Professional)

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful to include that information in your initial question since this seems like a case of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `flextable` package. I convert the data frame to a `flextable` object and then manually create a cell with text including a subscript in the header row.

```
library(officer)
library(flextable)

doc <- read_docx()
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:16, nrow = 4))
colnames(dat) <- c("Mean", "SE", "Min", "Max")

dat <- flextable(dat)

dat <- compose(dat, i = 1, j = 2, part = "header",
              value = as_paragraph("SE", as_sub("M")) )


doc <- body_add_flextable(doc, dat)
print(doc, target = 'test.docx')
```

### screenshot of resulting .docx

[image]

### references

- [flextable package overview](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html)
- [flextable::as_sub function](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/as_sub.html)